# Excluding files with variables from rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am looking for a rewrite condition for `.htaccess` to ignore files which have GET variables, so for example, I want it to ignore `foo.php?key=val`.

At the moment I have all files being routed to the `index.php` but I want users to be able to go to pages directly if they have anything after the `?` in the URI.

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this before your `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
```

See the [Apache Docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) for more info

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a RewriteCond for this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
```

That will match when the query string (the part following the "?") is empty.  For example:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php
```